# How do I pass and retrieve some datas when I load HTML content to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I pass and retrieve some datas when I load HTML content to a div ?

For example:

a.html:

```
<div id="topBar">
    <a href ="#" id="load_home"> HOME </a>
</div>

<div id ="content">        
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("b.html"); // HERE I want to pass datas, for example {firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Parker"}
    });
});
</script>
```

b.html:

```
<p><b>firstname: </b></p> // I want to retrieve the data {firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Parker"} to fill the text
<p><b>lastname: </b></p> // I want to retrieve the data {firstname: "Peter", lastname: "Parker"} to fill the text
```

How do I send my datas from a.html and how do i retrieve them in b.html ?

Maybe my way of thinking is wrong

Comment: You write *"send my datas from a.html and how do i retrieve them in b.html"*. Maybe you meant to get data from b.html to a.html? And what doesn't work?

Comment: not sure what you want... but probably Asynchronous JavaScript and XML https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax